# How do I add content dynamically to a masonry layout grid without changing the structure?

Tags: html, css, masonry

I'm working on a project that uses a masonry layout to display a list of multiple boxes with variable heights. But in this project, I use a filter that when clicked, filters all the boxes based o a class, and hides the one which doesn't have that class. The problem is that when I hide some boxes the whole structure of the layout brakes, and I cant simply remove the boxes because the filter can be deactivated and all the boxes appear again, or his class argument can also change, modifying the visible boxes again.
The Masonry script and CSS that I'm using it's this [this](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/#order-shifted-elements-in-a-flexbox-layout), above is the structure that I'm using for my boxes:

```
<div class="masonry-root">
    <div class="masonry-cell">
        <div class="masonry-item">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="masonry-cell">
        <div class="masonry-item">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Simply hide the elements didn't work.
- Removing and hiding the elements and then calling the script again also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is having trouble with this, I fond a better way to deal with my problem. 
Use the [Mansory Dessanto](https://masonry.desandro.com) plugin solved my problem completely. The structure of the code got simpler and you can add, hide, and remove blocks on the grid and it will organize it again.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content gray"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this structure I do all the layout preparation with a single function, like this:

```
// inicialize the plugin layout
$('.grid').masonry({
      // options
      itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});

// a simple event could trigger the next part
// hidding the selected element 
// (remove has the same efect but the elemnte would not appear again if 
// necessary)
$('.content.gray').hide();
// executing again the plugin 
$('.grid').masonry();
```